# schemaValidation error when using csv file with altair

Tags: python, altair, python-unicode

I am using altair with python to visualise a map.

```
with open('cities.csv', encoding='utf-8') as f:

    city = alt.Chart(f).mark_circle().encode(
    latitude='latitude:Q',
    longitude='longitude:Q',
    opacity=alt.value(0.5),
    color=alt.value('steelblue')
    )

city
```

I am getting this error:

SchemaValidationError: Invalid specification

```
    altair.vegalite.v4.api.Chart->0, validating 'anyOf'

    <_io.TextIOWrapper name='cities.csv' mode='r' encoding='utf-8'> is not valid under any of the given schemas
```

So I guess I need to use a different encoding? When I tried this before I was getting a unicode encode error which is why I have the with open line in the first place.

Thanks.

Comment: The problem might be that `Chart()` cannot accept an open file object as an argument.  Do you have documentation that states what the argument to `Chart()` is supposed to be?

Comment: In fact, it looks like `Chart()` expects to receive a Pandas dataframe as its argument. https://altair-viz.github.io/getting_started/starting.html#the-data

Comment: Perhaps you can use Pandas to create a dataframe from that csv file, and then use the dataframe as the argument to `Chart()`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to work with CSV files with altair is to use pandas (with the `read_csv` function). Here is an example, and you can read more about the [different other ways to load data in the docs](https://joelostblom.github.io/altair-docs/user_guide/data.html):

```py
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
                     'y': [5, 3, 6, 7, 2]})
alt.Chart(data).mark_bar().encode(
    x='x',
    y='y',
)
```

Comment: ok I did this and it now works. However there are more than 5000 rows so it doesn't display the chart, just gives the option to save it as png and a few others. What can I do?

Comment: @Primo4151 Please check out the docs, there are answers to most common questions like this https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/large_datasets.html